# Combining ListLinePlot graphics with Show

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, front-end, warning-messages

I'm new to Mathematica working on a project for school. I'm trying to show the deflection of a cord over time by breaking it up into 14 points and plotting the x,y coordinates of each point over time. I apologize in advance, I'm unsure how to format this post neatly....

```
ks=100;
kd=10;
gy=-10
d=1;
n=14;
dx=d/n;
Subscript[l, r] = dx;
tmax = 14;
Subscript[x, 14][t_] := 1;
Subscript[y, 14][t_] := 0;
Subscript[x, 1][t_] := 0;
Subscript[y, 1][t_] := 0;

xtable =
  Table[
   {Subscript[x, i]''[t] == -kd*(Subscript[x, i]'[t] - Subscript[x, i + 1]'[t]) - 
   ks*(Subscript[x, i][t] - Subscript[x, i + 1][t])*(1 - Subscript[l, r]/((Subscript[x, i][t]
   - Subscript[x, i + 1][t])^2 + (Subscript[y, i][t] - 
   Subscript[y, i + 1][t])^2)^0.5)- kd*(Subscript[x, i]'[t] - Subscript[x, i - 1]'[t]) 
   -ks*(Subscript[x, i][t] - Subscript[x, i - 1][t])*(1 - Subscript[l, 
   r]/((Subscript[x, i][t] - Subscript[x, i - 1][t])^2 + (Subscript[y, i][t] - 
   Subscript[y, i - 1][t])^2)^0.5), Subscript[x, i][0] == Subscript[l, r] (i - 1), 
   Subscript[x, i]'[0] == 0}, {i, 2, (n - 1)}];

ytable =
  Table[
   {Subscript[y, i]''[t] == 
     gy - kd*(Subscript[y, i]'[t] - Subscript[y, i + 1]'[t]) - 
     ks*(Subscript[y, i][t] - Subscript[y, i + 1][t])*(1 - Subscript[l, 
     r]/((Subscript[x, i][t] - Subscript[x, i + 1][t])^2 + (Subscript[y, i] 
     [t] - Subscript[y, i + 1][t])^2)^0.5)
     - kd*(Subscript[y, i]'[t] - Subscript[y, i - 1]'[t]) -
     ks*(Subscript[y, i][t] - Subscript[y, i - 1][t])*(1 - 
     Subscript[l, r]/((Subscript[x, i][t] - Subscript[x, i - 1][t])^2 + 
     (Subscript[y, i][t] - Subscript[y, i - 1][t])^2)^0.5), 
     Subscript[y, i][0] == 0, Subscript[y, i]'[0] == 0}, {i, 2, (n - 1)}];

(*Combines x,y tables to form ODE to be solved*)
ODE = Join[xtable, ytable];
(*Solves ODE for position over time*)
PSolve = NDSolve[{ODE}, Table[{Subscript[x, i][t], Subscript[y, i][t]},
{i, 2, n - 1}], {t,0, tmax}];
(*Solves ODE for velocity over time*)
VSolve = NDSolve[{ODE}, 
Table[{Subscript[x, i]'[t], Subscript[y, i]'[t]}, {i, 2, n - 1}], {t, 0, tmax}]; 

(*Position for all ten time steps*)
Positions = 
  Table[Evaluate[Table[{Subscript[x, i][t], Subscript[y, i][t]}, {i, 1, n}] 
  /. PSolve], {t, 0, tmax}];

Show[ListLinePlot[Positions[[1]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[2]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[3]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[4]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[5]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[6]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[7]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[8]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[9]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[10]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[11]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[12]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[13]]], ListLinePlot[Positions[[14]]], 
 ListLinePlot[Positions[[tmax]]], ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {Xpos, Ypos}]
```

I get the following errors:

Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show...

RGBColor called with 1 argument; 3 or 4 arguments are expected.

Coordinate Skeleton[14] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

I would like to get a line for every second combined on one chart. Could anyone please help fix and/or clean up my code? Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You don't need to solve for position and velocity separately, one
   `NDSolve` is enough.
2. You should omit the `[t]` in the list of unknowns in `NDSolve`.
3. I'd also `Flatten` the list of unknowns.
4. You can use `Plot` on the results from `NDSolve`.  There's no need for a `Table`.

Together:

```
PSolve = NDSolve[ODE, Flatten@Table[{Subscript[x, i], Subscript[y, i]}, {i, 2, n - 1}], {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[{Subscript[x, i][t], Subscript[y, i][t]}, {i, 2, n - 1}] /. PSolve], {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[{Subscript[x, i]'[t], Subscript[y, i]'[t]}, {i, 2, n - 1}] /. PSolve], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to see all the points in the cord at a given time, you could try something like:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[
  Table[{Subscript[x, i][tmax], Subscript[y, i][tmax]} /. PSolve, {i, 1, n}]],
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

P.S. Your post's formatting looks great.